# Include a SASS Mixin via another Mixin Parameter Value

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have this:

[image]

As you can see I currently have a conditional to include the button style mixins, is there anyway I can *automagically* include one? For example:

```
@mixin button($color)
  @include button-#{$color}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your markup above, I'm assuming you've tried interpolation already and it din't work. Just a thought - wouldn't an [extend](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) be more appropriate in this context? i.e. extend individual `button-*` mixins with a certain *roundedness*.

That being said, you already have the button `$color` parametrized, but you are taking a step back by adding an extra level of complexity of having a pre-defined mixin included depending on the variable value! I'm assuming that you've started with `button-blue`...`button-tree` mixins, and then a requirement came up needing a `$circle` toggle?

If you are, in fact, using `button-blue`...`button-tree` outside of the `button` mixin, I'd say it would be most maintainable to have the "multiple ifs" switch logic abstracted once to a function directive like

```
@function include-button-mixin($color) {
  @if $color == blue
    @include button-blue
  ...
}
```